# Link a Facebook Page to a Website using Facebook

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed a website with the Facebook Logo on it, and I want to link that Facebook Logo to a Facebook Page that I do not manage.

This is my HTML code so far...

And I want it to link to the following page:

https://es-es.facebook.com/pages/Hospital-y-Clinicas-San-Jorge/245739652112023

```
<li>
    <a href="https://es-es.facebook.com/pages/Hospital-y-Clinicas-San-Jorge/245739652112023" id="icon-facebook" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
</li>
```

Comment: I can't see an actual problem with your link. Could you provide more details?

Comment: Is the Facebook logo an `img` element, or a background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are putting the image on a totally different place, try it inside the `<a>` tag

```
<li>
    <a href="https://es-es.facebook.com/pages/Hospital-y-Clinicas-San-Jorge/245739652112023" id="icon-facebook" target="_blank">
        <img src="IMAGE_LINK" alt="Facebook"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

or of course you can do it with `<a href="#" style="`**`background-image:url(IMAGE_LINK)`**`"></a>`